# jstree: Cannot find element via an attribute

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm trying to select a node according a attribute I have created (db-id) however I have tested with many option and still I don't get the node. Even trying to get the node via the "id" of the tag "li", it doesn't work yet.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#jstree').jstree();

$('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
    x= $('#jstree').jstree(true).get_node('j1_1');
    alert(x[0].id);
...
```

In my example x is null. It seems that because the jstree is generated, it doesn't recognize the dynamic attributes of every "li". Of course I tried many more options like:

```
node = $('#jstree').find("li[id='j1_1']").closest('li');
node = $('#jstree').find("li[id='j1_1']");
node = $('#jstree.jstree-node').find("li[id=j1_1]");
```

but with no good results. Below a small structure of the generated jstree.

```
<div id="jstree">
<ul>
    <li db-id="1459">AAA004 - low-frequency amplifier
        <ul>
            <li db-id="1460">AAA005 - power amplifier</li>
            <li db-id="1461">AAA006 - voltage amplifier
                <ul>
                    <li db-id="1462">AAA007 - differential amplifier
                        <ul>
                            <li db-id="1463">AAA008 - operational amplifier</li>
                            <li db-id="1464">AAA009 - AC-coupled amplifier</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li db-id="1465">AAA010 - single-sided amplifier</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li db-id="1466">AAA011 - radio frequency amplifier</li>
    <li db-id="1467">AAA012 - wideband amplifier</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

** UPDATE **

The tree above is an example I was testing with.

Using with no $('#jstree').jstree() WORKS!!!...

```
x= $('#jstree').find("li[db-id='1462']");
alert(x[0].id);
```

but initializing with $('#jstree').jstree(), the code above works just for the first level but for the rest not anymore. Having said that, in the example, db-id="1459" will works but db-id="1460" wont!!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this what you want : http://jsfiddle.net/3q9Ma/21/

Comment: @Runcorn yep however, i tried to clean my tree, I made it smaller. "find" just works for the first level, for the rest doesn't work yet. If I remove the $('#jstree').jstree(), the find works really fine through the tree. There is something wrong with my jstree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsTree don't initialize all the nodes in the DOM.
Only the first level, a child will loaded in the DOM after opening the parent node.

First you only can get ID 1459, if you open it, then you can get the IDs 1459, 1460 and 1461. If you want to change the CSS for example, you can use the open_node.jstree event:

```
$('#jstree').bind("open_node.jstree", function (event, data) { ... }).jstree();
```